# notification not displaying in facebook native app

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I want to invite my friends to visit my website and I used following link to achieve  http://www.9lessons.info/2012/07/facebook-invite-friends-api.html

I follow the demo given on above link which sends app request to friends.
App request notifications display properly in Facebook website but not on Android and IOS mobile Facebook App.

I don't know the exact reason behind it, It might be possible its something related to app settings.

Please help. I am running behind my project deadline.
Any kind of help will be great appreciate

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Please consider reading this: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/faq#invite_to_app

App Requests should only be used for Games on Facebook Canvas, but not for external Websites. For those, use the Send and Message Dialogs. Or the Share Dialog to post the website URL on your own wall.

Keep i mind that App Requests are actually "Requests to use an App or get content in a Facebook game", but not "Requests to visit a website".